Positive reals that satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^{5}a_{i}=20$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{5}a^{2}_{i}=100$. Find min and max of $\max\{a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},a_{5}\}$
Let $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},a_{5}$ be non-negative real numbers that satisfy:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{5}a_{i}=20$$ and$$\sum_{i=1}^{5}a^{2}_{i}=100$$
How can I find the maximum and the minimum of $\max\{a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},a_{5}\}$?
Attempt:
So I could do the first bit which is finding the maximum using the following:
WLOG $a_{1}$ is the maximum then,
$100=a_{1}^2+\sum_{i=2}^{5}a^{2}_{i}$
Which then by Cauchy-Schwarz yields:
$4\sum_{i=2}^{5}a^{2}_{i} \ge (\sum_{i=2}^{5}a_{i})^2=(20-a_{1})^2 \iff \frac{(20-a_{1})^2}{4} \le \sum_{i=2}^{5}a^{2}_{i} = 100-a^{2}_{1}  \iff a_{1} \le 8$
Which corresponds to the solution $(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},a_{5})=(8,3,3,3,3) \implies$ maximum is $8$.
Now I couldn't find a way to find the minimum value of $\max\{a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},a_{5}\}$, any sort of hints is very much appreciated!
(Oh and for those interested, this problem was apart of the Indonesian TST back in 2023)

Denote $L = \max_{i=1,..,5} \{a_i \}$, because $0\le a_i \le L$ then we must have
$$\begin{align}
&a_i(L-a_i) \ge0 \hspace{1cm} i=1,...,5\\
\implies &L\sum_{i=1}^5a_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^5a_i^2\\
\implies &20L\ge100\\
\implies &\color{red}{L\ge 5 }
\end{align}$$
The equality occurs if and only if $a_i(L-a_i) =0$ for all $i=1,..,5$ or  one of these number is equal to $0$, these $4$ remaining number are equal to $5$ (e.g. $a_1 = 0, a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = 5$).

So the $a_{i}(L-a_{i})=0 \implies a_{i}=0$ or $a_{i}=L=5$ for all $i=1,2,3,4,5,$ which doesn't work right?

@JAB for each $i=1,..,5$, $a_i$ is equal to $0$ or $5$. They are not necessarily all equal to each other. I dont know why you said it does not work?

Oh wait so, $a_{i}=0$ or $a_{i}=5$ implies that one of them is equal to $0$ while the rest is equal to $5$?

@JAB suppose there are $k$ variables gets value $5$ (so $5-k$ remaining variables gets values $0$), then we must have: $$k\cdot 5=20$$ and $$k\cdot 25=100$$ it’s evident that $k$ must be equal to $4$. Q.E.D

I see, thanks @NN2!

Hint:
Observe,
$$5\cdot\sum_{i=1}^5a_i=\sum_{i=1}^5a_i^2\implies \sum_{i=1}^5(5-a_i)a_i=0.$$
What happens if all the $a_i$'s are less than $5$? Does there exist a solution if $a_1=5$ ?
